# Ruby RSpec Net:HTTP - How to test request payload is as expected while mocking a response

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a very!! new ruby and Rspec user struggling to understand how to unit test that an API request has set the expected request payload while mocking a response from an external API. I have implemented API requests using Net:HTTP to limit dependencies.

**Method being tested**

```rb
 def lint (url, path, headers={ "Content-Type" => "application/json" }, timeout=10)
            if yamlContent = GitLab::Lint::Client::YamlFile.new(path).get_json_content()
            
              uri = URI.parse(url)

              req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, headers)
              req.body = { content: yamlContent }.to_json
              
              https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
              https.use_ssl = true
              https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
              
              response = https.request(req)
          
              case response
                  when Net::HTTPSuccess
                      puts "Linting request successful"
                      return JSON.parse(response.body)
                  when Net::HTTPUnauthorized
                      abort("#{response.message}: invalid token in api request?")
                  when Net::HTTPServerError
                      abort('error' => "#{response.message}: server error, try again later?")
                  when Net::HTTPBadRequest
                      puts "Bad request..." + req.body
                      abort("#{response.message}: bad api request?")
                  when Net::HTTPNotFound
                      abort("#{response.message}: api request not found?")
                  else
                      puts "Failed validation\nJSON payload :: #{req.body}\nHTTP Response: #{response.message}"
                      abort("#{response.message}: failed api request?")
              end
            else
              abort("\nLint request failed, problem encountered reading yaml file")
            end
end
```

**RSpec test**

```rb
require "gitlab/lint/client/api"

RSpec.describe Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api do
    
    describe "#initialize" do
        it "initialises" do          
            api = Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api.new
            expect(api).to be_instance_of(Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api)
        end
    end

    describe "#lint" do
        before(:each) do
            @response = instance_double(Net::HTTPSuccess, body: @response_body, message: 'OK')
            @response_body = { 'status' => 'valid', 'errors' => [] }.to_json
            
            @request_mock = instance_double(Net::HTTP::Post)
            allow(@request_mock).to receive(:[]=)
            allow(@request_mock).to receive(:body=)
            allow(Net::HTTP::Post).to receive(:new).and_return(@request_mock)

            @http_client_mock = instance_double(Net::HTTP)
            allow(@http_client_mock).to receive(:use_ssl=)
            allow(@http_client_mock).to receive(:verify_mode=)
            allow(@http_client_mock).to receive(:request)
            allow(Net::HTTP).to receive(:new).and_return(@http_client_mock)
            allow(@http_client_mock).to receive(:request).with(@request_mock).and_return(@response)
                  
            @endpoint_url = 'http://gitlab.com'

            @fileName='test.yml'
            
            allow(File).to receive(:exist?).with(@fileName).and_return(true)
            allow(File).to receive(:readable?).with(@fileName).and_return(true)
            allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with(@fileName).and_return("image: ruby:latest")
        end

        it "lints successfully" do
           
            # for a valid case we want:
            # - test that the request body was set with content as expected
            # - simulate the response to be { status: "valid", "errors": []}

            api = Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api.new
            api.lint(@endpoint_url, @fileName)

            expect(@request_mock.body).to have_received({ content: {'image' => 'ruby:latest'} }.to_json)
        end
    end
end
```

Running the test gives the following erroroneous ouput:

```rb
Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api
  #initialize
    initialises
  #lint
OK: failed api request? # this output signifies that the case structure has not recognised the response as a HTTPSuccess instance
```

The response is not being seen as an instance of **Net::HTTPSuccess** in the case structure of my *lint* method under test. How do I mock a *Net::HTTPSuccess* instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular way to do this is called [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). You can find a lot of docs and a RailsCast on the project web site. Basically, it works like this:

- You set VCR on "record mode".
- You make a request to the real backend. VCR records the request and response.
- You set VCR to  "playback" mode.
- When you run your tests, you can use VCR to make assertions about the request and response (in other words, that it matches your expectations).

It's a robust way to verify that HTTP requests are doing exactly what you want them to.

Comment: Thanks for responding, appreciated :) Is VCR ok for use with unit tests as well?

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of testing frameworks supported.